# ionic error: cannot find symbol import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPluginPathHandler

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

While running the build for android, the following is what I am getting.

```
Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
PROJECT_PATH/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/file/FileUtils.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
```

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPluginPathHandler;

FYI: iOS is running perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Did you figure out how to solve it?

Comment: Just removed the npm `@ionic-native/file`